# How can I get more children to grow up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, minecraft-millenaire

I'm using the Millénaire village mods in Minecraft. I have a Japanese-style village with at least one of every building. I have 30 villagers, including 6 children. Some of the places I had built, like the Bath House and Squid Farm, don't have anyone in them.

According to the in-game FAQ, to get more villages I need to get children to grow up. It also says something about increasing the chances of it, by having the house have sweet bread. Although I put bread inside the chests of all the houses in which children are in, no one is growing up.

How do I get more children to grow up?

Comment: Uh... Modded, yes; technical/troubleshooting no.

Answer (score -1):

Well, firstly, if you just want adult villagers, then...

If you are in creative mode:

- Get villager spawn eggs from the creative inventory and right click the spawn eggs.
- Do `/summon Villager (x) (y) (z)` in chat or a command block.

If you are in survival mode, then:

- Gather the resources to build a villager breeder. Let them all breed and wait! A good example of one by Unarybit is here:
- Cure a zombie villager. You simply have to trap one, hit it with a splash potion of healing, feed it a super golden apple and wait!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This won't help as it refers to vanilla village mechanics while OP asks for help with a mod that completely overhauls villagers. In vanilla babies inevitably grow after 20 minutes of being in loaded chunks. Millénaire has much more complex prerequisites.

Comment: Also, you can't heal zombie villagers with splash pots of healing and you don't need a 
"super" apple. It's a weakness potion and a regular golden apple.